# Scipy sparse matrices are not memory efficient in cosine similarity

Tags: python, scipy, out-of-memory, sparse-matrix

I am trying to implement cosine similarity using scipy sparse matrices, as I am getting memory error with the normal matrices (non-sparse). However, I noticed that the memory size (in bytes) of the cosine similarity of sparse and non-sparse matrices is almost the same when the size of the input matrix (observations) is large. Am I doing something wrong, or, is there a way around this? Here's the code where the input has 5% as 1's and 95% as 0's.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from scipy import sparse
A = np.random.rand(10000, 1000)<.05
A_sparse = sparse.csr_matrix(A)
similarities = cosine_similarity(A_sparse)

# output sparse matrices
similarities_sparse = cosine_similarity(A_sparse,dense_output=False)

print("1's percentage", np.count_nonzero(A)/np.size(A))
print('memory percentage', similarities_sparse.data.nbytes/similarities.data.nbytes)
```

Output of one rune is:

```
1's percentage 0.0499615
memory percentage 0.91799018
```

Comment: `similarities` is 92% 'full'

Comment: Your `A` is too dense to produce a sparse similarity.  With an average of 50 1's per row you still have a good chance of a nonzero similarity. Try `<.005` and you'll see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating @hpaulj's comments into an answer:

Both your calls to `cosine_similarity` return the same underlying data. That cosine similarity matrix isn't mostly zeros, so using a sparse format doesn't save space.

Input data that's mostly zeros doesn't necessarily (or even typically) yield a cosine similarity matrix that's mostly zeros. Cosine(i,j) = 0 only occurs(*) for a pair of rows (i, j) of the matrix if they have no values in any of the same columns.

(* Or if the dot product otherwise comes out to 0, but that's a side point here.)